# What is the correct preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I want to ask about the preposition that I have to use in my sentence, which is:

Aruba is an island in the Caribbean Sea.

Comment: "In" is the correct idiomatic preposition.

Comment: Yes, an island being 'in the sea' is not exactly the same as a shark being 'in the sea', but 'in' is a very hard-working word.